# Do not understand 400 error when using ComponentDidMount() - React Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Ok, so when I use ComponentDidUpdate() the get call works just fine, except for the fact that it infinite loops.  When I use this code:

```
componentDidMount() {

        const getRequest = async() => {
            try {
                const result = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${this.state.lat}&lon=${this.state.long}&
                exclude={part}&appid=${this.state.apikey}&units=imperial`);

                console.log(result);
            }
            catch(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
        }

        getRequest();
}
```

I keep getting the 400 error.  Can anyone help me out with this, I am lost.  Its a personal project and not homework before anyone asks.

Comment: What your console outputs? Any errors? Also, shouldn't it be `exclude=${part}`?

Comment: 400 means Bad Request. Need more information to answer this .

Comment: You should check network part of developer console to see the request that you send to server. Probably some of your variables are undefined and that is why you get bad request from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move your async function outside of componentDidMount and call it from there.
And it seems that you are also using a variable named **part**. You should also provide it to the function as well.
Since it is giving a 400 error, it must be something related to your parameters mostly coming from your state.

```
  getRequest = async (apikey, lat, long, part) => {           
    try {
        const result = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&
        exclude={part}&appid=${apikey}&units=imperial`);
        console.log(result);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { apikey, lat, long } = this.state;
    this.getRequest(apikey, lat, long, 'daily');
  }
```

Comment: Ok, so this gave me the fix.  I moved the function into the class declaration of the component.  but I called it when the geolocation api callback function was invoked.  This way it has the latitude and longtitude.  Thank you Nostromo!